How to get data types for each element in a list of lists using iteration and nested for-loops in Python?
There is a list comprised of three separate lists containing different data types. I want to retrieve the data type for each item in each list using iteration and nested for-loops.
x_list is the name of list of lists
for n in range (len(x_list[0])):
    for m in (x_list):
        print (type(m))

All items returned with class 'list'. Pretty sure this is not iterating over each item correctly.

You create but do not use n.

"x_list is the name of list of lists" - then why would you expect type(m) to be anything other than list?

Show an example of the list and of your expected output.

In your outer loop you iterate over the first element of the list and do not use n. So your inner loop prints <class 'list'> for element of x_list and repeat this output len(x_list[0]) times.
You can try something like:
x_list = [['abc', 12, (65, 0)], ['xyz', complex(1, 1), 0], [10,5, 'z']]

i = 0
for x in x_list:
    print('list', i)
    for y in x:
        print('   ', type(y))
    i += 1

Output:
list 0
    <class 'str'>
    <class 'int'>
    <class 'tuple'>
list 1
    <class 'str'>
    <class 'complex'>
    <class 'int'>
list 2
    <class 'int'>
    <class 'int'>
    <class 'str'>


#Let us assume the following list
ls = [[5, 'a', 5.04],[True, 'b', 4]]

for x in ls:
    for y in x:

        #For the sake of understanding, printing both element and type
        print(y, type(y))

'''Output:
5 <class 'int'>
a <class 'str'>
5.04 <class 'float'>
True <class 'bool'>
b <class 'str'>
4 <class 'int'>
'''

